# Ubuntu 14.04 shutdown like when that it had a power cut

Tags: 14.04, shutdown

I've a problem after my new install of Ubuntu. I successed to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1 (in legacy mode/non UEFI), but I've a problem. When I'm in Ubuntu, my pc shut down like if it had a power cut. And that doesn't happen in Windows.

Do you've an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: You mean it will shut itself down automatically right after you boot into the Ubuntu desktop?

Comment: It's not just after the boot into Ubuntu, it's a little bit at random ...

Answer (score 0):

Your computer could be overheating pretty bad when going to ubuntu. Have you seen the temperature in BIOS when you boot to ubuntu? Tell in celsius.

Comment: My BIOS doesn't show the temperature